# Como alterar option a partir de retorno JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

Como faço para alterar o `option` abaixo, com base no retorno JSON:

```
<select name="modalidade-frete" id="modalidade-frete">
    <option value="0">0 - Por conta do emitente</option>
    <option value="1">1 - Por conta do destinatário/remetente</option>
    <option value="2">2 - Por conta de terceiros</option>
    <option value="9" selected>9 - Sem frete</option>
</select>
```

Obs.: desejo remover o valor **default** *9* e alterar para o valor correspondente ao retorno JSON, por exemplo: `data.mod_frete = 1`, passando a ficar assim:

```
<select name="modalidade-frete" id="modalidade-frete">
        <option value="0">0 - Por conta do emitente</option>
        <option value="1" selected>1 - Por conta do destinatário/remetente</option>
        <option value="2">2 - Por conta de terceiros</option>
        <option value="9">9 - Sem frete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta definir o valor do `<select>` com o valor da opção desejada:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('modalidade-frete');
sel.value = 1; // no caso, sel.value = data.mod_frete
```

Comment: bfavaretto funcionou em partes. Ao utilizar o inspetor do Chrome, o `option` de `value=9` ainda está selecionado.

Comment: O inspetor está te mostrando o HTML original que o browser recebeu. Uma coisa é o atributo `selected` (que está no seu HTML), e outra é a propriedade `selected` (que você está acessando via JS). O atributo só define o valor inicial da propriedade.

Comment: Compreendi, mas há alguma forma de fazer essa alteração, mesmo que seja apenas "visual"?

Comment: Você pode tentar [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) / [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), mas sinceramente não vejo nenhum bom motivo para fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('destino.php', {data:'data'}, function(response){
  $('#modalidade-frete').val(response.valor_desejado_para_o_option);
}, "json");
```

[Em resposta ao seu comentário @luccasrodrigo]

```
$.post('destino.php', {data:'data'}, function(response){
  if($('#modalidade-frete').attr('selected') == true){
    $('#modalidade-frete').attr('selected', 'false'); // Oculta o selected no HTML
  }
}, "json");
```

Comment: Olá Marcelo, realizei algumas pequenas edições no código, e obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Olá novamente Marcelo, como já editei a resposta e não foi incluso na edição o fechamento do seletor `#modalidade-frete`, você mesmo poderia editá-la e acrescentar a aspa simples.